# How to loop over the keys of a HasMap where the keys follow a certain structure?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I have a `HashMap pdf = new HashMap<String, String>()` with keys that follow a certain convention:

```
PilotFirstname Bob
PilotName Jones
PilotDOB 12/12/2001
PilotAddress 123 Any Street
CopilotFirstname Jim
CoPilotName Jones
CopilotDOB 13/02/1997
CoPilotAddress 456 Any Street
```

Notice how the keys are formed as `<role><property>`.  Each person is prefixed with there role, and there are 4 details for each person (Name, Firstname, DOB, Address) to go into the POJO. The prefixes are Pilot, CoPilot, CabinCrew1 through 6.

I made a start on the code. The fields come from a PDF:

```
List fields = new ArrayList(); // list to store PDF fields
fields = acroForm.getFields(); // Get PDF fields
Iterator fieldsIter = fields.iterator(); // Iterator for the fields
// Create Hashmap "pdf" storing PDF field names & values
pdf = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (fieldsIter.hasNext()) {
        PDField field = (PDField) fieldsIter.next();
        // Next line removes braces for dropdowns and any leading whitespace
        pdf.put(field.getPartialName(), field.getValueAsString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").trim());
}

    public void createPerson(Map<String, String> pdf, String role) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setLastName(pdf.get(role +"Name"));
    person.setFirstName(pdf.get(role +"FirstName"));
    person.setAddress(pdf.get(role +"Address"));
    person.setDateOfBirth(pdf.get(role +"DOB"));
    System.out.println("Stop");
}
```

Whats the best way to loop over each person in the hashmap (need to identify the prefixes (roles)).

I need to extract the details of each person into a Person POJO, one POJO per role.

How to approach this? Should I loop over the Hashmap looking for fields that end in "Name" and then search the hashmap for one of the other four fields with same prefix?

**Environment is Java 7.**

Comment: Yes, looping over the Hashmap would work.

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: one possible solution is since you know that Name, Firstname, DOB, Address will be there for everyone, you can get all the strings having FirstName. Now  get all the roles by subtracting FirstName from string of previous step. And finally now you can generate all the maps

Comment: I wouldn't try to figure out how to get the values from the Map into the Pojo, rather then fixing the place which writes the values into the Map. That code should create the Pojos instead.

Comment: Do you need, for example, a single POJO containing all the details of all the pilots?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point to extract the properties on a per role basis:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static class Pojo {
        public Pojo(String property1, String property2) { }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("role1property1", "a");
        myMap.put("role1property2", "b");
        myMap.put("role2property1", "c");
        myMap.put("role2property2", "d");

        List<String> roles = myMap.keySet().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.endsWith("property1"))
            .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf("property1")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String role: roles)
        {
            // do something with it
            String a = myMap.get(role + "property1");
            String b = myMap.get(role + "property2");
        }

        // or

        List<Pojo> pojos = roles.stream()
            .map(role -> new Pojo(myMap.get(role + "property1"), myMap.get(role + "property2")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```